# Finding Components in Complement of Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a graph G having N vertices. For each vertex, I am given adjacency vector, denoting the elements adjacent to vertex in G.

For example say :- 
N = 4, and adjacency matrix is like :
[1] = {3,4}
[2] = {3}
[3] = {1,2,4}
[4] = {1, 3}

[image: Graph Image]

What I am required to find is the number of connected components in the complement of G [image] 
in say O(N) or O(Nlog(N)). I tried but my approach is O(N^2). I am applying dfs and iterating i from 1 to N and checking if i is not present in the adjaceny matrix of source vertex (in dfs) and then continuing DFS.

Answer (score 0):

Similar Problem was asked in a contest yesterday.
[Problem link](https://codeforces.com/contest/1243/problem/D), [Solution link](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/71216).

Comment: Hi. Your links are helpful, but it would be better if you could summarise their contents in your answer. On the one hand, one would then not have to go off-site, and on the other hand the information would be preserved if the links go stale.